# how to get Text value from TextBox in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, datalist

i am trying to retrieve Text value from a TextBox when i click on a LinkButton,both of which are in ItemTemplate of a DataList.But it is returning a null value.

this is code of datalist in the aspx page:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyField="UserId" OnItemCommand="itemcommand"
                OnItemDataBound="Data_Bind">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<%#System.String.Format("ViewProfile.aspx?aid={0}",Eval("UserId")) %>">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Img" Width="100px" Height="80px" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px"
                                        BorderColor="Aqua" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#System.String.Format("../Content/Upload/{0}", Eval("UserDetail.UserPhoto")) %>' />
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserDetail.Firstname")%>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lastname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserDetail.Lastname")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="post" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post.post")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Like" runat="server" CommandName="onLike" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Post.PostId") %>'>Like</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="lk" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Share" runat="server" CommandName="onShare" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Post.PostId") %>'>Share</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="sh" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                          <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomment"  runat="server" Height="40px" Text="abc" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
                          <input type="text" id="cmnt1" name="cmnt1" runat="server" />
                           &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="Comment" runat="server" CommandName="onComment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Post.PostId") %>'>Comment</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Image ID="Img2" Width="50px" Height="40px" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px"
                                                        BorderColor="Aqua" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#System.String.Format("../Content/Upload/{0}", Eval("UserDetail.UserPhoto")) %>' />
                                                    <asp:Label ID="fname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserDetail.Firstname")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserDetail.Lastname")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="cmnts" Text='<%#Eval("Comments.Comment")%>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:DataList>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
 protected void itemcommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "onLike")
        {
            var k = e.CommandArgument;

            User ObjUser = new User();
            ObjUser = (User)Session["user"];
            ObjUser.Post.PostId = Convert.ToInt64(k);

            PostService.OnLike(ObjUser);

            DataList1.DataSource = PostService.GetPosts(ObjUser);
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "onComment")
        {
            var k = e.CommandArgument;

            TextBox cmnt = (TextBox) e.Item.FindControl("txtcomment");
            HtmlInputText cmnt1 = (HtmlInputText)e.Item.FindControl("cmnt1");
            User ObjUser = new User();
            ObjUser = (User)Session["user"];
            ObjUser.Post.PostId = Convert.ToInt64(k);
            ObjUser.Comments.Comment = cmnt.Text;

            PostService.OnComment(ObjUser);

            DataList1.DataSource = PostService.GetPosts(ObjUser);
            DataList1.DataBind();

        }
        if (e.CommandName == "onShare")
        {
            var k = e.CommandArgument;

            User ObjUser = new User();
            ObjUser = (User)Session["user"];
            ObjUser.Post.PostId = Convert.ToInt64(k);

            PostService.OnShare(ObjUser);

            DataList1.DataSource = PostService.GetPosts(ObjUser);
            DataList1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

FindControl doesn't search for a control recursively. It will only look for the control in the current children. Given the structure you are using, you will have to search within the child controls of the item.

You will have to write your own recursive function to search all children for this control.

Or you could write an extension method so that you can use this to recursively search where ever you need to. This function I found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx) should help.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(this Control control, string id)
    {
        if (control == null) return null;
        //try to find the control at the current level
        Control ctrl = control.FindControl(id);
        if (ctrl == null)
        {
            //search the children
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                ctrl = FindControlRecursive(child, id);
                if (ctrl != null) break;
            }
        }
        return ctrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand,all the linkbuttons are accessible but the textbox is not.i think the textbox control is a direct child of datalist,like the rest of them.i can find the textbox control but its text value is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox

string Key = Datalist.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();

TextBox Textboxvalue = (TextBox)(e.Item.FindControl("txtQuantity"));

//You will get the value in Textboxvalue
```